# SQL Server 2012. Trigger to convert row into Nvarchar, and write to single row in another table

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I am using the adventureworks2012 database. 
I have an audit table called AuditTable and I would like to write all the inserts from  the person.address table onto the prevValue column as one large string of text.

I am trying to convert every inserted value into char first then write to auditTable(prevValue) but it keeps just writing a NULL row.

Here is my Person.address trigger called sPerson.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Person].[sPerson] ON [Person].[Address]
AFTER INSERT 


    AS
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.AuditTable(PrevValue) 
     SELECT 
        N'ID : ' + CAST(AddressID AS NVARCHAR(20)) + N'Address: ' + AddressLine1 + 
        N', ' +AddressLine2 + N','+ City + N',' + CAST(StateProvinceID AS NVARCHAR(20)) +   + N',' + CAST(PostalCode AS NVARCHAR(20))+ + N',' + CAST(SpatialLocation  AS NVARCHAR(200)) + + N',' + CAST(rowguid AS NVARCHAR(100))+ + N',' +CAST (ModifiedDate AS NVARCHAR(40))
     FROM Inserted
     END
     GO
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) for a clue on this:

> When SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is ON, concatenating a null value with a string yields a NULL result.

and you have to write code these days with it `ON`, because in the future, they're not going to support turning this `OFF`.

So what you need to do is, for each column that might contain a `NULL` value, wrap you access to it with a [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) that supplied an appropriate default, e.g. if `StateProvinceID` is the only nullable column, you'd have:

```
 ... N',' + COALESCE(CAST(StateProvinceID AS NVARCHAR(20)),'<No State>') + N',' ...
```

Where `<No State>` is whatever you want to appear when the column is null.

---

As an aside, I'd probably, instead of doing all of this string concatenation, use the XML transformation facilities of SQL Server - and store the resultant XML in the audit table. It's just as flexible in terms of supporting different schemas, but it does at least hold out some hope that you can query this audit table for interesting data using the XML querying facilities.

The XML transformation facilities cope with `NULL`s automatically (by omitting the element/attribute) rather than you having to apply the above string workarounds.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I might do the XML Transformation because it seems allot simpler.